# Is there any Anti Virus product which provides a .Net (or COM) API?

Tags: .net, antivirus

We need to send uploaded files from our CMS website to any antivirus product as a POC. Are there any AV products out there that provide a .Net/COM API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clam AntiVirus](http://www.clamav.net/) has an API available under the GNU GPL which you can probably wrap up with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

If for any reason you don't want their code in your process, you can also use their (very simple) socket protocol: open a socket and send it SCAN *filename*, or send it STREAM and it will send back a port number to which you can then send a byte stream to scan.

Comment: +1 for free software and simple interop over sockets
Documentation link: http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/html/node25.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Microsoft's Antivirus API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537365(VS.85).aspx). I believe it provides a way for an application to integrate with the installed antivirus software.

Comment: MS AntiVirus API is not an AntiVirus! it's a "port" to let AntiVirus Vendors use their AntiVirus software to scan Office documents and automatic download codes such as ActiveX from IE!

Comment: I know it's not an antivirus product by itself, but I thought it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will not have any luck with using an AntiVirus API, cause they are all well protected and the code and methods are locked with the Gods, but there are methods like [OPSWAT](http://www.opswat.com/antivirussdk.shtml) that you can use an AntiVirus already installed in the system and have kind'a control with that, please read the website for more information.