# How to invoke STATUS_VIRUS_INFECTED 0xC0000906 programmatically?

Tags: winapi, antivirus, windows-defender

When trying to access files quarantined by Windows Defender or another antivirus program, I receive 0xC0000906 STATUS_VIRUS_INFECTED error. How can I programmatically lock a file, so another program will see this error code? Is there Windows API the security software is using?

Comment: write own mini-filter driver, which return this status. but not think that exist sense do this

Comment: Whether you want to check if a file contains a virus programmatically? If so, I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602670/how-would-you-programmatically-test-a-file-for-viruses

Comment: I don't want to check the file, I want to quarantine it the way Windows Defender/AntiVirus software does, or at least notify the WD/AV that a file needs to be quarantined. Perhaps the "mini-filter driver" would work to block access to the file.